# Table's rows height works differently depending on which browser I use

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

This little piece of code dynamicaly creates a table, but it doesn't work the same in different browsers.
Ideally I need to dynamically set the rows height (and that itself is a problem I can't solve yet), but while trying to figure out how to do it I found my table to be displayed in different ways, depending on which browser I use.
It works in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome.
In Chrome the first row fills almost all the table's height, leaving little space for the other rows.

By the way, this code creates just 3 rows, but later it will erase its original content and create 5 rows with different content (the erase and recreate part is not implemented here, but it's done and works in another code already).
I'm stuck with this tr height matter...

```js
    CreateRow(0);
    CreateRow(1);
    CreateRow(2);
    
    function CreateRow(iRow){
        var Html_Content = document.getElementById("id_MainTable").innerHTML ;
        Html_Content += StandardRow(iRow);
        document.getElementById("id_MainTable").innerHTML = Html_Content;
    }

    function StandardRow(iRow){
        var iColumn, Html_Content = "";
        for (iColumn = 0; iColumn < 10; iColumn++){
            Html_Content += "<td id='Row" + iRow + "Col" + iColumn + "'>-</td>";
        }
        Html_Content += "</row></table>";     
        return Html_Content;
    }
```

```css
    html, body{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    table{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }  
    table tr{
        height:33%;
    }
    table td{
        width: 10%;
        font-size: 5vmin;
        text-align: center;
        border: solid 1px;
    }
```

```html
    <table id = "id_MainTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this function:

```
function StandardRow(iRow){
        var iColumn, Html_Content = "";
        for (iColumn = 0; iColumn < 10; iColumn++){
            Html_Content += "<td id='Row" + iRow + "Col" + iColumn + "'>-</td>";
        }
        Html_Content += "</row></table>";     
        return Html_Content;
    }
```

you are closing `table` tag by mistake. Your result would be like:

```
<table id = "id_MainTable">
<td><td></row></table>
<td><td></row></table>
<td><td></row></table>
</table>
```

Also you should initiate `Html_Content` with `<tr>`

change the function to:

```
function StandardRow(iRow){
        var Html_Content = "<tr>";
        for (var iColumn = 0; iColumn < 10; iColumn++){
            Html_Content += "<td id='Row" + iRow + "Col" + iColumn + "'>-</td>";
        }
        Html_Content += "</tr>";     
        return Html_Content;
    }
```

Comment: Not enough... Invalid HTML according to Chrome. See my version

Answer (score 0):

Once you have corrected your table tag problem as [@rezKesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60945236/10432250) pointed out, you may still have height issues. I have in the past with properly formatted html. My solution was to assign Mozilla based browsers their own attribute values.

Example:

```
table tr{
  height:33%;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix('') {
  table tr{
    height:30%;
  }
}
```

There may be better methods, but this has always worked for me. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: The issue was more invalid HTML than this

Comment: Thansk for your help, but the code works in mozilla already. It's in Chrome that it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

More than one issue

- You do not start your row with `<tr>`
- You close your row with `</row></table>` instead of `</tr>`
- Chrome will try to "fix" invalid HTML. You need to add a `<tbody></tbody>` since you now have several tbodies inserted by Chrome

```js
CreateRow(0);
CreateRow(1);
CreateRow(2);

function CreateRow(iRow) {
  document.getElementById("id_MainTable").innerHTML += StandardRow(iRow);
}

function StandardRow(iRow) {
  let Html_Content = ["<tr>"]; // I prefer using an array
  for (let iColumn = 0; iColumn < 10; iColumn++) {
    Html_Content.push("<td id='Row" + iRow + "Col" + iColumn + "'>-</td>");
  }
  Html_Content.push("</tr>");
  return Html_Content.join("");
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

table tr {
  height: 33%;
}

table td {
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="id_MainTable"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks  a lot. The whole problem was the absence of tbody.

Comment: I tried just the tbody tag in my original code, and that alone solve the problem. Later on I corrected the "</row></table>", but even with this line the code worked just fine. Anyway, thanks again! I'll probably ask another question related to this code, as I mentioned earlier. :-)

Comment: I did get rid of quite a few lines too :)

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention that... thanks again. :-)